# As3 Split on a Carriage Return

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, split, carriage-return

Can anyone tell me how to use the split() function in as3 to split Strings with Carriage Returns?

This is usually done with " \n ", but it doesent seem to work in this case, with or without de quotes.

Comment: Yes, to no avail. It just gets me the whole file. The problem doesen't seem to be the "\r\n" specifically, its the fact that I don't know how to use a non-printable character in the split function. With quotes, it goes as text, without them it, the flash returns an error.

Comment: here work well.

    string = string.split("\r")

Comment: The main problem is different OS means (probably) different line breaks. As far as I know there are at least three different types used by human kind: `"\r"`, `"\n"` and `"\r\n"` I need to split on all of them and remove the non-printable characters. There is no solution here for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try spliting like this

```
var yourArray:Array = YourString.split(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

Comment: This works, thanks. "\r" worked too. I had no ideia that It was "\r" instead of "\n". Any ideia what "\n" is used for? Seem like I just got mixed up with another Regular Expression. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: \n is newline too.

try this : trace('a'+String.fromCharCode(13)+'b'+'\n'+'c'+'\r'+'d');

You will see that is one line for each letter.

But you dont know if the text you are spliting are yousing \n or \r.

Vote up the answer if it helped you :)